# Formatting archive file names in JCA File adapter

Tags: soa, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware, soa-suite

When we select the "archive file" option in the File adapter configuration wizard,
the archive that is created has the name something like "**filename_token_timestamp**" or "**filename_timestamp**".

How can I format this file name so that the archived file name is the same as the original filename.

Current format  : "**filename_timestamp**"
Required format : "**filename**"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

A-Configure the File Adapter normally, specify the file name pattern at design time.

B-In the Invoke activity (BPEL process), as you wire it to a File Adapter partner link, you get the Edit Invoke dialogue.

C-Go to properties and configure **"jca.file.FileName"** with value set to a variable that will be populated at runtime in some assign activity before the invoke activity. This overrides the name mentioned at the design time.